# Error al intentar realizar cuenta con un valor vacío

Tags: java, android

Bueno el error que recibo en `logcat` cuando se detiene la aplicación es este:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0

Sé porque se produce pero no cómo seleccionarlo, lo que realizo es lo siguiente:

Tengo dos clases `MainActivity` y `Main5Activity` en la primera tengo dos `checkbox` si selecciono los dos guarda un *nombre* y *número* por cada `checkbox` en `SharedPrefences` ahora al ir a `Main5Activity` cargo esos datos guardados en `SharedPreferences` y realizo una suma de ambos *números* hasta ahí todo perfecto.

El problema viene cuando solo selecciono un `checkbox` y solo mando un *nombre* y *número* que al intentar realizar la cuenta se me detiene la aplicación con el error que comento arriba, por lo tanto sé que el error se produce porque no encuentra un número para realizar la cuenta.

Pues bueno, mi pregunta es cómo puedo solucionarlo, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando no envie un *nombre* y *número* el valor de ese *número* sea 0 y ni *nombre* ni *número* se muestre en mi `layout`? O si hay un una forma mejor de realizar esto..

Este es mi código:

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioButton opc1, opc2;
    TextView persona1, persona2, numero1, numero2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        opc1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.opc1);
        opc2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.opc2);
        persona1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        persona2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        numero1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        numero2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // guardo los datos en sharedpreferences

        persona1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("persona1", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });

        numero1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("numero1", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });

        persona2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("persona2", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });


        numero2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("numero2", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });

        opc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                persona1.setText("Persona1");
                numero1.setText("10.00");

            }
        });

        opc2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                persona2.setText("Persona2");
                numero2.setText("5.29");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

`Main5Activity`:

```
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView uno, dos, tres, nombrepersona1, nombrepersona2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        uno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uno);
        dos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dos);
        tres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tres);
        nombrepersona1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombrepersona1);
        nombrepersona2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombrepersona2);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // cargo datos SharedPreferences

        nombrepersona1.setText(prefs.getString("persona1", "") + ":");
        uno.setText(prefs.getString("numero1", ""));
        nombrepersona2.setText(prefs.getString("persona2", "") + ":");
        dos.setText(prefs.getString("numero2", ""));

        // sumo aux0 + aux1
        BigDecimal aux0 = new BigDecimal(uno.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal aux1 = new BigDecimal(dos.getText().toString());
        aux1 = aux1.add(aux0);
        // envio el resultado a:
        tres.setText(" " + aux1.toString().replace(".",","));
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Perfecto! Además de añadir que el valor sea 0, añado `            text.setVisibility(View.GONE);` cuando sea null y ya tengo la solución perfecta! Crea una respuesta para darte la respuesta como solución, gracias ! :) @mmartinez7

Comment: Exacto! Me alegra haberte ayudado, he creado la respuesta, me gustaría borrar o editar el comentario para no generar info duplicada y quede bien clara la respuesta pero no tengo muy en claro como, si alguien me puede ayudar le agradezco

Comment: Desde la web al lado del mensaje te sale una X le das encima y lo borras, desde la aplicación dándole encima al mensaje y luego a borrar, editar no se puede pasado un tiempo. @mmartinez7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por qué no simplemente haces un chequeo antes de crear los objetos BigDecimal, y en función de si son nulos o no los textos operar con ellos?

Es decir, puedes controlar si

```
uno.getText() != null && !"".equals(uno.getText())
```

y si eso evalúa a `true`, crear el BigDecimal con el valor del `getText()` o crearlos con "0" en caso contrario.

De esa manera te aseguras de estar sumando `0 + 0` (cuando ambos son vacíos), `0+dos`, `uno+0` (cuando alguno de ellos tiene un valor) o `uno + dos`